# Flagging a code style suggestion as "Not an answer" wrongfully declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I've recently flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41011717/817643) (10k only link) with the "not an answer" flag.

Adding the answer here, since it was deleted by the owner:

> Only a short notice: change
>
> ```
> Players(int value3) 
> {
>   this->value3 = value3;
> }
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> Players(int value3) : value3(value3) {};
> ```
>
> It will save you code lines and improve readability (just a hint for
>   you :) )

While factually correct, it does not try to present itself as an attempt to answer, starting with the phrase "Only a short notice" and ending with "just a hint for you".

It has the strong sense of a comment written as an answer by a user that doesn't have sufficient rep to comment. And I'm not the [only one who holds this opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011602/defining-and-instantiate-class-at-once#comment69231173_41011717).

Is it not as cut and dried as I thought?

Comment: "This doesn't answer the question" != "It should be flagged as NAA"

Comment: @Tunaki Well that certainly helps. But the flag description itself doesn't qualify "comment". And I certainly think "giving unrelated tips for better code style" to be a comment.

Comment: Hm. I would really agree with you that this is NAA as it is just code cleanup advice and makes no attempt to actually answer any part of the question.

Comment: I can see how someone without expertise in the language might not realize that it is, in fact, nothing but unsolicited code review. The language used is a strong but imperfect indicator that it's NAA; sometimes, careless answerers will leave genuine answers that have very similar disclaimers about how they aren't allowed to comment (putting the savvy reviewer in the awkward position of *not* deleting something the poster almost admits outright should be deleted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That *answer*, for me at least, looks, smells and moves like an answer and as such an *Not An Answer* flag will get declined, if your flag is handled by a moderator that applies most of the guidance provided [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

This is caused by the fact that flags are handled without the context of the question. A reviewer needs to take an extra step to recreate that context (scroll down or click the link). An moderator need to take much more steps, as explained by [Bhargav Rao](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao):

> The mod queue shows the first 200 or so chars while reviewing. One more click we can see the complete answer, Another one, we see comments, Another one, we see the question, Another one, we see the whole post.

If you stumble upon something that looks, smell and moves like an answer but it really isn't, use a custom mod flag and explain the context needed to make the correct call if the post is a true NAA. Or organize some 20K-ers to delete vote these mishaps. That needs just 3 users.

Keep in mind that down voting such answers is always an option, as the tooltip says: *this answer is not useful*. Leaving a comment for others is preferred.

Comment: Well, the lack of context for moderators is news to me. That certainly explains why this happened. Thanks for the tips as well.

Comment: Hmm, such is the problem with these foolish guidelines for what is/is not an answer. In no way does this "look, smell, or move" like an answer to me. StoryTeller already said why not: the verbiage of the answer, *everything that is not part of the code blocks*. I still haven't looked at the question, and it is abundantly clear to me that this is not an answer.

Comment: @CodyGray Oh, I would love to have the NAA rules being more relaxed so it could also be applied to posts that doesn't answer *the* question. Or I need coaching, I don't know. If you have a better answer or explanation for this I'm happy to re-open the question.

Comment: My explanation for this is that flag handing is broken because people are unwilling to hit the delete button. And this is one of the many reasons why we have rampant quality problems. I have no real explanation for why, other than perhaps people are gunshy after instances of public shaming on Meta. I don't really think that makes for a good answer, though. I just disagree with your characterization here; this is very clearly not an answer from my perspective.

Comment: Public shaming on Meta never gets fun. Anyway, I think we disagree but I edited in that my answer is more my perspective and added the delete route without mentioning how on earth you should organize that.

Comment: *moderator needs to take an extra step* - This is kinda wrong. They need to take more than a single extra step. The mod queue shows the first 200 or so chars while reviewing. One more click we can see the complete answer, Another one, we see comments, Another one, we see the question, Another one, we see the whole post. So it's more than one step.