# Can I help SO with closed questions?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

I have recently written a piece of code that tries to predict closing Stack Overflow questions. Could SO let me use it for helping it to predict question closure?

I crawled SO and got about 8,000 questions and trained an ANN (artificial neural network) with the addition of some numerical features such as user reputation at the time the question was asked. I don't think my approach is very important here, but I used [GloVe](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe) for word representation of questions. Now it has a 27% precision on closed questions (97% overall). I can use a very large data set, and I can use another numerical features like user history for closed questions, etc.

My question is this system can be better by my work and also contribution of others, but would SO let me use this system (of course freely) for better prediction of closed questions?

On some days I see about 9k questions in the Close Vote queue. But with automation it can be handled faster. Maybe less accurate, but humans make wrong decisions too.

BTW, this is just for improving SO (I love SO), and I'm also sure there are more people love to help SO and with contribution of them this might become a very useful feature.

Like the spam detection system that SO uses, create a system for predicting closed question using question body and title and OP information.

Comment: ... I have no idea what you're asking here.

Comment: @Cerbrus , Can we help SO to predict closed questions?

Comment: @Arman As Cerbrus said, that's not clear.  Help how?

Comment: I don't know what is the problem ? get an question body and OP and predict it is closed question or not? Is it clear now? as spam detection of SO

Comment: What are you suggesting? If your question is _"Can we help <...>"_, then the answer is a simple "yes". And that would make this question pretty pointless.

Comment: @Cerbrus OP has trained a neural net to predict closure. Question is if it can be helpful. Not unlike Smokey, I guess. I'd like to see it pitted against Triage review.

Comment: @Arman: Instead saying _"But my question __is__ clear"_, try to improve it. Make it even better. Right now, it's a wall of text lacking formatting, and it's very unclear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I think you posted this a bit too soon. Make your system work first. Don't rely on screen scraping (really don't), but only the API or SEDE. And when you have some nice graphs about how your thing is improving SO / helps in moderation, come back with a Meta post :)!

Comment: @Tunaki I just wanted to know if it is worth I try to improve it , and also it is not just mine , with help of others it can be better of course

Comment: Sure, we love bots around here! Improve it all you can. At worst, you'll learn incredible things about machine learning ;). (We also have bots doing machine learning in [SOBotics](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) chat room).

Comment: FWIW, do not miss the huge Stack Exchange public data dumps. Naturally, a lot of ground truth for ya! https://data.stackexchange.com/help https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you can. Though you'll need 3k reputation points for close voting.

[NobodyNada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3476191/nobodynada) and I have created a chatbot called [FireAlarm](https://stackapps.com/questions/7183/firealarm-detecting-low-quality-questions-with-machine-learning) to detect low-quality questions with machine learning. It runs in the in [FireAlarm Development](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123602/firealarm-development) with the threshold set at 55 (more threshold reports more posts), in [SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) with a threshold of 45, and in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) with the threshold at 35.

If you want to cast all your close votes on reports posted by FireAlarm, you may want to visit the development room as that is more like a log of all reports, but if you want *extremely* accurate reports, you may [want to use this search](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=FireAlarm-Swift&user=6373379&room=41570) as SOCVR has the lowest threshold meaning it will have fewer, but accurate reports.

Comment: I didn't know there is stackapps community! I think this is the best way for create apps for helping SO

Comment: @Arman Nice job! It looks like your algorithms are *waaaaay*  more accurate than ours (especially since I know next to nothing about machine learning).  If you're interested, we could incorporate your algorithms into our project.

Answer (score 33):

> Maybe less accurate, but humans make wrong decisions too.

I think this is the completely wrong way to think about this. If we are going to automate aspects of moderation, it needs to be done accurately. If not, all you are doing is adding *more* work for a human, somewhere, to fix. There are already community run, automatic, solutions being utilized:

- [Can a machine be taught to flag comments automatically?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280546/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-comments-automatically)
- [Can a machine be taught to flag Non-Answers and post comments on them automatically?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343065/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-non-answers-and-post-comments-on-them-automatica)
- [Can a machine be taught to flag spam automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically)

I'm sure there are others too, but I was involved in those three to varying degrees, so I am more aware of how they operate. In each of those cases, reducing accuracy was **not** the goal.

> My question is this system can be better by my work and also contribution of others but would SO let me use this system (of course freely) for better prediction of closed questions?

If you are going to build something to automate closing posts, it needs to be accurate. It can't close topics that should remain open and it can't keep topics open that should be closed.

It sounds like you have a first generation of your project. Great! Improve it. Work on that accuracy though. The projects listed above were not weekend things. They took months and years to get as accurate as they are.

As it currently sits, I think you'll need to provide a lot more details on how it works and behaves before the community is comfortable with you utilizing it.

Comment: Sure, it needs too much improvements to be applicable , my goal here was is SO let me and are others like to help me for improve it , and also this is not weekend thing too , I used a paper for this.

Comment: And also closed questions like off-topics way too much harder too be predict compared to spam questions , I don't think so it can be as accurate as spam detection system

Comment: It may be to early for that assumption @Arman. There are a couple [papers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data) that have attempted to do so. I haven't read them in a while, so I don't remember their accuracy. Take a look through those though.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can help SO with this neural network.

We have a chatbot, Smoke Detector, that detects spam with high accuracy. This chatbot was created by normal Stack Exchange users - not by people who work for Stack Exchange.

You can do the same with your program. You use the the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) to get information from the site directly (this is preferred over screen scraping, and easier to work with too).

Smokey Detector asks the chatters if something is spam and should be flagged. Your bot would ask the chatters if something should be closed.

Note, BTW, that (as @Ashish Ahuja points out in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344267/can-i-help-so-with-closed-questions/344268?noredirect=1#comment450737_344268)) that you cannot yet use the Stack Exchange API for posting messages in chatrooms. This, you will still have to do with a little screen scraping.
Also, not all chatrooms allow bots to post messages; or if they do, they may have rules governing bots posting. Do make sure that the people in the room agree with your bot posting these Close requests.

Comment: "You use the the Stack Exchange API to post things in a chatroom.", AFAIK that's wrong. You cannot use the SE API to use chat, though there have been few FR's for that. The SE API will still be useful to the OP though as that provides a lot of info instead of doing screen scrapping like the OP did now.

Comment: @AshishAhuja I had a quick look at the SE API, and it looks like you're right. I've updated the answer.