# Show pending edit suggestions in Low Quality Review

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I just came across this answer, which [originally had been link-only](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44073695/1):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44073695/103167

The review now includes the edit, like so:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16176903

The first reviewer came across the post about an hour after the edit was suggested but 2 minutes before the edit was accepted, and came to an inappropriate conclusion, and the auto-generated comment is completely ridiculous (it comes an hour after the comment mentioning the edit).

[image]

**The fact that the answer is already being salvaged is critical information** for reviewing "Low Quality" posts.

Can we please have the suggested edit shown on the review screen, and "Accept Edit" made into one of the buttons for resolving the review?

Comment: The edit isn't even a valid edit.  It's just editing an entirely original answer into someone else's answer.  That's not appropriate.  If Steve wanted to post that content, he should have posted his own answer rather than editing it into someone else's.

Comment: @Servy: First, that really doesn't diminish the need for LQR to show pending edits.  Secondly, that content is an example of the technique linked.

Comment: Yes, this example not being an example of the situation you're describing doesn't mean that the information isn't relevant to a reviewer; linking to a suggested edit review in LQP (when one exists) seems reasonable enough.  As for the edit, that doesn't change anything; it's still not appropriate to edit your own original solution into someone else's answer.

Comment: This is semi-related but more guidance in general on when it's more appropriate to add a new answer (especially a late/accepted answer) vs editing in content would be appreciated. I know of a couple link only answers, I'd like to use information from that link and add code and information in a new answer, if it's okay to add a new answer. If it's not okay to add a new answer in this case, I will suggest an edit. I left a comment to the answerer asking for them to edit in more information a while ago but they never responded.

Comment: @jrh the guidance is already there: [if you see something that needs improvement, click edit!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) I get flabbergasted how many people bash their heads trough a wall, for something so simple.

Comment: @Braiam: But! If the link-only answer would rely entirely on quoting copyrighted material, that's a no. Probably. If the answer needs to be written from scratch by the editor based on guesswork, that's a no. Etc. It really is not as simple as "go ahead and edit all the problems away".

Comment: @Braiam I agree with you, but when I brought this up in chat a long time ago (do you know how I can find old chat messages?) the consensus was that edits that added content to link only answers (copyright or not) would be rejected as "deviates too much from the original intent of the post" because the expected experience level of the editors is not enough to verify whether the code you posted matches the answerer's intent. I don't necessarily agree with it, but I follow it because when I tried these kind of edits I always got at least one or more reject votes...

Comment: ... also note that this question is case in point, Isn't Servy for example saying that editing code to a link only answer is improper and it should be a new answer? Also note that if I wrote my own code based a page linked by a link only answer, to avoid any copyright problems, it would be even harder for editors to verify that my code matches the answerer's intent.

Comment: @jrh again, the solution is simple: can't fix it, close/delete it. Remember, that bad answers are usually results of a bad question.

Comment: @Braiam Makes sense, though are you implying that if I find a bad Q/A pair on a subject that I was researching I should just ask a new, better question and self-answer? Wouldn't that just end up getting marked as a dupe and downvoted for posting something similar to a question that already exists? (i.e., lack of research effort)

Comment: @jrh no, because we (supposedly) close duplicate questions to the better pair. If your Q/A is superior, "obviously" we wouldn't close it.

Comment: @Braiam noted, thanks. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Also those suggesting posting a late answer [should keep in mind that there is a bot set up to auto-flag late answers under certain conditions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343065/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-non-answers-and-post-comments-on-them-automatica). Late answerers should be careful to follow site rules, and watch out for things that might trigger it accidentally like using question marks or mentioning users.

Comment: @jrh: A late answer here was fine.  All the existing answers saying it can't be done like that are wrong in the new language version.